# Atualizar um array no state do React?

Tags: javascript, react

Estou tentando extrair os elementos de um `array` e passar para
outro `array` no `state` mais ainda sem sucesso, meu código está assim:

```
this.state = {lista[]};
//(No metodo)
let v = "";
for(var j=0;j<=vetor.lenght-1;j++){    
     v = vetor[j];
     this.state.setState((state) => { state.lista.concat(v); }); 
}
```

O que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Seguinte cara copiar um `array` e criar outro ou até adicionar outro é simples mas, o seu código atual não ajuda, poderia melhorar?

Answer (score 0):

Bom, minha abordagem pro teu problema seria a seguinte:

```
//(No construtor)
    this.state = {lista : []};

//(No metodo)
    let arr_temp = this.state.lista;
    for(var j=0;j<=vetor.lenght-1;j++){    
      arr_temp.push(vetor[j])
    }
    arr_temp = [...arr_temp];
    this.setState({lista: arr_temp})
```

Poderia também fazer isso sem o for, usando o spread pra juntar os dois arrays em uma temporaria dentro do método, e depois setar o state, mas fica a teu critério

Comment: Não funfou....ele retorna lista.lenght = 0.

Comment: Ué, retorna lista.length aonde? tenta usar um console.log assim:                                                              
this.setState({lista: arr_temp}, ()=>console.log(this.state.lista))

Comment: Eu to testando o resultado assim: console.log("TAMANHO DE LISTA : "+this.state.lista.length) e dá ZERO...

Comment: @Ninja2112 colocou o teste no callback do setstate, como eu respondi ali? só pra certeza que tu tá pegando o state dps de ele mudar

Comment: Sim....mesma coisa

Comment: estranho, não tem nenhuma lógica complicada por trás desse código, deveria estar fazendo o que você quer. Não tem um problema com a variável *vetor* por acaso?